# Populating multiple tables when creating new primary record

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been working on my first webapp and I hit a bit of a wall. I have a table in my db set up as follows:

> student_id(student_id, first_name, last_name, bdate, etc...)

I also have several tables for classes set up similarly to this

> class_table(id, student_id, quiz_1, quiz_2, etc....)

`student_id` is how I would like to track everything, from my understanding, this would be a primary key that would become a foreign key on the class tables.

What I would like to do is create an entry for the student on each class table when the php script I am writing creates a new student. This is what my query looks like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO student_id(0, '$first_name', '$last_name'.... etc);".
         "INSERT INTO class_table(0, LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$quiz_1', $quiz_2'...etc)";
```

Is this the right way to do this? I keep getting an error from my `mysqli_query...` so I am guessing this  is where the problem is. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query()` (and `mysql_query()`) will only execute a single query.  You would need to perform two calls to `mysqli_query()` or use `mysqli_multi_query()`, which will execute multiple queries in one call.

Comment: I'll play around with that tonight. Is this considered a "good" practice or is there a preferred method for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `VALUES` clause:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO student_id VALUES (0, '$first_name', '$last_name'.... etc);".
         "INSERT INTO class_table VALUES (0, LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$quiz_1', '$quiz_2'...etc)";
```

and you will need to use the [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) function. See the example at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#106126:

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) { 
    $i = 0; 
    do { 
        $i++; 
    } while ($mysqli->next_result()); 
} 
if ($mysqli->errno) { 
    echo "Batch execution prematurely ended on statement $i.\n"; 
    var_dump($statements[$i], $mysqli->error); 
}
```

You could also create a stored procedure, and call it with all the needed parameters:

```
CALL insert_student('$first_name', '$last_name', '$quiz_1', $quiz_2', ... etc);
```

Here's an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_student(
    IN  v_first_name    VARCHAR(50),
    IN  v_last_name     VARCHAR(50),
    IN  v_quiz_1        VARCHAR(255),
    IN  v_quiz_2        VARCHAR(255)
)
DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
proc: BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO student_id VALUES (0, v_first_name, v_last_name);

    IF ROW_COUNT() <= 0 THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        SELECT 0 AS result;
        LEAVE proc;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO class_table VALUES (0, LAST_INSERT_ID(), v_quiz_1, v_quiz_2);

    COMMIT;

    SELECT 1 AS result;
END;
```

Comment: Can I use call to insert into multiple tables when I create the procedure or is it similar to mysqli_query, being limited to one insert on one table?

Comment: Yes, I added an example to the answer.